# Would courts sentence differently if we used a different numeral system?

Tags: punishment, sentencing

I hear a lot in the media about people sentenced to go to jail especially for a number of years divisible by 10.

Does our numeral system affect it? If we used base 7 (so "10 years" will mean 7 years, "20 years" will mean 14 years and so on), would courts sentence the same?

Comment: Interesting question.  Might be a stretch to consider this on-topic here.  I suspect that the only objective answer might come from an analysis of much earlier systems of justice in cultures that were not so heavily base-10.  Maybe the Babylonians?

Comment: I love this question.  However, you might get better answers in [Cognitive Sciences](http://cogsci.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Vote to close, but +1 for an interesting question.

Comment: There might be something to this.  A quick look through Hammurabi's Code shows an abundance of tens, but also a scattering of sixes, threes, twenties, and thirties, as you might expect from a base-60 counting system.